# Split XML variable, join and insert into a temp table XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have an `XML` variable that contains the following `XML`:

```
<Fruits>
  <Fruit>
    <Type>Apple</Type>
    <FruitID>1</FruitID>
    <MoreInfo>
      <Info Name="GreenApples" Value="3900" />
    </MoreInfo>
  </Fruit>
  <Fruit>
    <Type>Orange</Type>
    <FruitID>2</FruitID>
    <MoreInfo>
      <Info Name="Oranges" Value="1100" />
    </MoreInfo>
  </Fruit>
</Fruits>
```

I am trying to create a temp table that looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE #XmlTable (
    email nvarchar(100),
    xmlNode XML
)
```

The output that I am aiming for is:

```
email | xmlNode

one@email.com | <Fruit><Type>Apple</Type><FruitID>1</FruitID><MoreInfo><Info Name="GreenApples" Value="3900" /></MoreInfo></Fruit>
two@email.com | <Fruit><Type>Orange</Type><FruitID>2</FruitID><MoreInfo><Info Name="Oranges" Value="1100" /></MoreInfo></Fruit>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to convert it to XML when I split it and insert it in the table.

I have the following SQL that is doing the job, but how do I convert it to XML?

```
INSERT INTO #XmlTable
SELECT  EOR.email, 
        xmlNode.Col.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS XML
FROM @outputXML.nodes('/Fruits') xmlNode(Col)
CROSS APPLY @outputXML.nodes('/Fruits/Fruit/FruitID') xmlValue(i)
INNER JOIN #EmailsOfReceivers EOR
ON EOR.ID= xmlValue.i.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
```

It works fine, but of course the xmlNode column doesn't have the XML tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible way :

```
INSERT INTO #XmlTable
SELECT  EOR.email, 
        fruit.x.query('.') AS XML
FROM @outputXML.nodes('/Fruits/Fruit') fruit(x)
INNER JOIN #EmailsOfReceivers EOR
ON EOR.ID = fruit.x.value('FruitID[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/37431/6)**

Basically, shred the XML on `<Fruit>` nodes, then you can use `query()` instead of `value()` to get the XML tags.

Side note: I'd return `FruitID` as `int` instead of `nvarchar(max)`, if possible.

Comment: @Apostrofix yes, it necessary to guarantee that there is maximum one element returned. There will be an error if you remove it.

Comment: What If the whole `XML` is wrapped in a `ROOT` tag? Would it be possible to get the Fruit nodes and do the join?

Comment: Not sure I understand this *new problem* you're asking now. If the entire XML structure remains the same other than the `ROOT` tag, simply change `/Fruits/Fruit` to `/ROOT/Fruits/Fruit` ..

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. But then the output is like: `<Fruit><Type>Orange</Type><FruitID....` - Can I wrap it in the `<Fruits>` tag too?

Comment: like `'<Fruits>' + CAST(fruit.x.query('.') AS varchar(max)) + '</Fruits>'` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.query('.')` for your xml column:

```
DECLARE @outputXML XML

SELECT @outputXML = '<Fruits>
  <Fruit>
    <Type>Apple</Type>
    <FruitID>1</FruitID>
    <MoreInfo>
      <Info Name="GreenApples" Value="3900" />
    </MoreInfo>
  </Fruit>
  <Fruit>
    <Type>Orange</Type>
    <FruitID>2</FruitID>
    <MoreInfo>
      <Info Name="Oranges" Value="1100" />
    </MoreInfo>
  </Fruit>
</Fruits>'

INSERT INTO #XmlTable
SELECT  EOR.email, 
        xmlNode.Col.query('.') AS MyXML
FROM @outputXML.nodes('/Fruits/Fruit') xmlNode(Col)
INNER JOIN #EmailsOfReceivers EOR
ON EOR.ID = xmlNode.Col.value('FruitID[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```